# Where are lifecycle methods defined in React's source code?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

where is `shouldComponentUpdate` and other lifecycle function defined in react source code? I was digging in the react source code, and simply can't find the definition.. anyone can give a hint?

or to put it this way: where specifically did react decide to return 
 for `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifecycle methods aren't 'defined' in React's code, so to speak - it simply checks if they exist on your component's instances at certain points in their lifecycle, and if so, it runs them.

For example, here's [some of the code from the React reconciler package that checks `shouldComponentUpdate`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2ae4c6215891c67aed17c22261db74c1f078f663/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L165):

```
if (typeof instance.shouldComponentUpdate === 'function') {
  startPhaseTimer(workInProgress, 'shouldComponentUpdate');
  const shouldUpdate = instance.shouldComponentUpdate(
    newProps,
    newState,
    newContext,
  );
  stopPhaseTimer();

  /* ...and so on... */

  return shouldUpdate;
}
```